# Fatal error: Class 'SoapVar' not found. Versión de PHP 5.4.16

Tags: php, soap

Tengo el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Class 'SoapVar' not found in

La linea en la que da erro es esta:

```
 $var = new SoapVar($xmlRQ, XSD_ANYXML, $cadena, $wsdl);
```

Puede ser por la versión de `PHP`?? porque se ha cambiado en el servidor

Answer (score 1):

Intenta hacer lo siguiente:

1. Verifica que la extensión `SOAP` esta activa.

   1. Crea un archivo en la raiz de tu servidor, por ejemplo, `phpinfo.php`, con este contenido:

      ```
      <?php
         phpinfo();
      ```
   2. Abre un navegador e indica en la URL al mismo, por ejemplo, `http://localhost/phpinfo.php`
   3. Busca que `Soap Client` este activo, ejemplo:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWDtj.jpg]

2. Activar la extension `SOAP`

   1. Busca tu `php.ini` (la ubicación depende de como has hecho la instalación)
   2. Localiza y remueve el `;` al principio de la linea `extension=php_soap.dll`
   3. Reinicia tu servidor Apache
   4. Vuelve a realizar el punto 1